# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (how to find udf with issue)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to debug code from a developer no longer in the organization which uses many UDFs and it's failing with

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined
>   function

But the error does not show the name of the udf with issues, only

> $anonfun$1: (string, string) => string

How can i find the name of the function having issues? is there something like a mapping from $anonfun$1 to function name?

Answer (score 1):

UDFs in Scala DSL don't have a runtime name. Consider this for example:

```
val f = udf((_: Int) / 0)
Seq(1)
  .toDF("foo")
  .select(f($"foo"))
  .show()
```

The function `f` is not known by Spark. However, the full stack trace reveals the source of error which is carried in the `cause` property of the `SparkException`

```
Failed to execute user defined function(SqlTest$$Lambda$547/666911607: (int) => int)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function(SqlTest$$Lambda$547/666911607: (int) => int)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1066)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.If.eval(conditionalExpressions.scala:63)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at lab.SqlTest.$anonfun$new$2(SqlTest.scala:28)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcII$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcII$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.$anonfun$f$2(ScalaUDF.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1063)
```

Comment: The thing is that the developer based it's code completely  on UDFs(there's many of them) so even if the cause is shown, i still have the problem: of all UDFs(and there's many) which one is having the issue(even if i know the cause)

Comment: The source file name and the line number is in the stack trace so in the example above the failure is in the UDF that is defined in file `SqlTest.scala` at line 28